# How to find out and control where the Perl modules stored locally?

Tags: linux, perl, build, perl-module

Some Perl modules, such as `DBI`, need to be downloaded, compiled **and installed**.

I'm connecting to a remote production testing computer, for which I have only my local user password (no root, for obvious reasons). I've used `wget` to download some external modules that I need, such as `DBI`, and unpacked these resulting in directories like `~/modules/DBI-<version>`.

Normally, when compiling something for Linux, you run `configure` to pre-configure everything before installation; and one of its switches is `--prefix=<some_dir>`, which controls where the compiled executable and all compiled dependencies will ultimately end up.

But for Perl modules, you don't run `configure`, so my first question is:

- Can I control where the compiled modules (e.g. `DBI.pm`) go when I run `make`? If so, how?

Failing that, I at least need to update `@INC`, so I can refer to the module; so my second question is:

- How can I find out where the compiled modules went when I ran `make`?

I can't issue `make install` after compiling, and moreover, I've been asked not to. (I've been asked to design the script so that it doesn't rely on external modules being in the standard system path.)

Comment: I hope you don't mind -- I've taken the liberty of shortening your question, so that more people will read it, and so you can hopefully get better answers.

Comment: @ruakh, No, I don't mind. I just made it that long so that people stop confusing things, like they did with my other posting about that topic. That's why it was the "OT" comment in the beginning and the last comment in the end about better explanation "this time". ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation directory is set when the makefile for the module is built. Each module comes with a `Makefile.PL` which must be run to build the makefile, taking into account the current Perl configuration. `Makefile.PL` has the option `PREFIX` that says where the build is going to be installed, so after unpacking the module's distribution and `cd`ing to the unpacked directory you can say

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/module/directory/path
make test
make install
```

This process is described in the Perl documentation - read `perldoc perlmodinstall`. You could go into the CPAN shell and use the 'o' (lower-case) oprion that allows you to change the options passed to `makefile.PL`, but I think the manual build/test/install is more straightforward and gives you more control over the process.

Remember to add

```
use lib qw(/module/directory/path);
```

to the start of your program to make sure Perl searches the new directory for modules.

Comment: After those 3 commands mentioned will I be able to build dependencies? I.e. I issued them for 'DBI', and need to build 'DBM:mySQL'. Will it find the DBI dependency? Thx.

Comment: @Igor: since you've accepted my answer did it work for you? Were you able to install `DBD::MySQL` locally on top of `DBI`?

Comment: I will try it tonight. Sorry didn't have time before but I have a feeling it will work. Will test tonight and let u know.

Comment: Well apparently in order to run 'perl Makefile.PL' I need an access to the mysql installation. And it is not available since it is hosted on the different machine. In fact in order to test the script I was given an alias to connect to DB. I am asking if it would be possible to install those 2 modules at least. If not any idea to overcome? I'm not really familiar with the compilation/installation procedure... Thank you.

Comment: @Igor: as I described, you need to download and unpack the modules from CPAN. You can do that locally and independently of the main installation. The whole process is described in `perldoc perlmodinstall`.

Comment: Apparently I was too fast. It didn't work. I tried to install a dependency and the main module failed on 'make test'. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

perl modules should either be installed with the distributions's system, like you did with gentoo or pkg_add on BSD, etc. or by using CPAN. Don't do what you're doing, that is going to confuse you & the system.

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install DBI"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it try to install the module in the standard system path? It might very well be OK on Windows, but not on Linux, where you need a root password...

Comment: CPAN is the right answer, it can install system-wide or in a private directory of yours.  Read its man page for the details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`local::lib`](http://metacpan.org/module/local%3a%3alib) to install Perl modules in a custom directory. Modules so installed can be used from Perl scripts:

```
use local::lib '/path/to/custom/directory';  # Custom modules can be `use`d from hereon
```

[`cpanm`](http://cpanmin.us/) uses [`local::lib`](http://metacpan.org/module/local%3a%3alib) internally when you use the `-l` or `-L` flag. To install a module in the current directory:

```
cpanm -l. DBI
```

Comment: "cpanm -1. DBI". This is number 1 or small letter l? Also is "cpanm" part of standard Perl installation on Linux? Finally I want to install them in ~/modules so I do: "cd ~/modules; cpanm -1. DBI", correct? And this way it will update @INC variable, right?

Comment: It is the letter `l` and not the digit `1`. `cpanm` is not part of standard Perl and you will have to install it manually. To install to `~/modules`, you can use: `cpanm -l~/modules DBI`. In the program: `use local::lib '~/modules'` will automatically modify `@INC` for you.

Comment: I don't have 'cpanm' program on the remote machine and I can't control what is going in there. How/where I can get/install this program? Thank you.

Comment: Also, when reading 'man cpanm' I didn't see the '-l' option anywhere. Will it work?